# Flutter Listview colour but not text remains visible outside of container

Tags: flutter, listview

I am trying to render a listview and divider in a column and have used a container to restrict the height.The text of the List Tiles is shown only within the Container however the listtile colour is shown outside the container. I want this layout but for the colour to be only shown within the container as well.

```
                     Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 20,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              tileColor: Colors.red,
                              leading: Text("Test"),
                            ),
                            Divider()
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i didnot get what you want . 
are you talking about listTile isnot taking the full height of container or container taking extra height or overflow of text

Comment: please post the code for the entire output in your question so that the problem can be diagnosed.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I want the lsitview to be just inside the container ie. the grey box in the middle of the screen below 'Jobs'.The text on the list tiles is displaying correctly and only being displayed inside the container however as you can see the colour and the list tile are still visible outside of the container just with no text.

Comment: can you check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the **ListTile** with the **Card** to avoid overflow; similar to the example in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html).

```
Card(
    child: ListTile(//...)
    //...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

updated

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SEList extends StatelessWidget {
  const SEList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: Text("User Profile"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Name"),
                      Text("Name"),
                      Text("Name"),
                      Text("Name"),
                      Container(
                        height: 70,
                        child: Text(
                          "Job",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                /// 70% of screen for listView
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .65,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    child: Text("Text $index"),
                    height: 70,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                    thickness: 1.2,
                  ),
                  itemCount: 30,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.upload_file,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```